# Simple Neural Network from scratch using NumPy (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ai, machine-learning, neural-network

I added learning rate and momentum to a neural network implementation from scratch I found at: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-your-own-neural-network-from-scratch-in-python-68998a08e4f6

However I had a few questions about my implementation:

- Is it correct? Any suggested improvements? It appears to output
  adequate results generally but outside advice is very appreciated.
- With a learning rate < 0.5 or momentum > 0.9 the network tends to
  gets stuck in a local optimum where loss = ~1. I assume this is
  because step size isn't big enough to escape this but is there a way
  to overcome this? Or is this inherent with the nature of the data
  being solved and unavoidable.

  ```
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


  def sigmoid(x):
      return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))


  def sigmoid_derivative(x):
      sig = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
      return sig * (1 - sig)


  class NeuralNetwork:
      def __init__(self, x, y):
          self.input      = x
          self.weights1   = np.random.rand(self.input.shape[1], 4)
          self.weights2   = np.random.rand(4, 1)
          self.y          = y
          self.output     = np.zeros(self.y.shape)
          self.v_dw1      = 0
          self.v_dw2      = 0
          self.alpha      = 0.5
          self.beta       = 0.5

      def feedforward(self):
          self.layer1 = sigmoid(np.dot(self.input, self.weights1))
          self.output = sigmoid(np.dot(self.layer1, self.weights2))

      def backprop(self, alpha, beta):
          # application of the chain rule to find derivative of the loss function with respect to weights2 and weights1
          d_weights2 = np.dot(self.layer1.T, (2*(self.y - self.output) * sigmoid_derivative(self.output)))
          d_weights1 = np.dot(self.input.T,  (np.dot(2*(self.y - self.output) *
                                              sigmoid_derivative(self.output), self.weights2.T) *
                                              sigmoid_derivative(self.layer1)))
          # adding effect of momentum
          self.v_dw1 = (beta * self.v_dw1) + ((1 - beta) * d_weights1)
          self.v_dw2 = (beta * self.v_dw2) + ((1 - beta) * d_weights2)
          # update the weights with the derivative (slope) of the loss function
          self.weights1 = self.weights1 + (self.v_dw1 * alpha)
          self.weights2 = self.weights2 + (self.v_dw2 * alpha)


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      X = np.array([[0, 0, 1],
                    [0, 1, 1],
                    [1, 0, 1],
                    [1, 1, 1]])
      y = np.array([[0], [1], [1], [0]])
      nn = NeuralNetwork(X, y)

      total_loss = []
      for i in range(10000):
          nn.feedforward()
          nn.backprop(nn.alpha, nn.beta)
          total_loss.append(sum((nn.y-nn.output)**2))

      iteration_num = list(range(10000))
      plt.plot(iteration_num, total_loss)
      plt.show()
      print(nn.output)
  ```

Comment: "Is it correct?" Did you test it?

Comment: @Mast Yes but it gets stuck in a local optimum where loss = ~1 occasionally, and I wanted to know if I'd inputted momentum correctly.